# Populating data on click of image link

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am stuck on angular side when populating the data on click of an image(map).

My home page Home.jsp page is getting displayed successfully having URL as http://localhost:7001/LocalMarket/ .But when I am clicking on a particular state image link . It is throwing 406 error and the URL changes to http://localhost:7001/LocalMarket/home.web?statechoice=ME .
I have debugged and the data is getting populated from Spring MVC side to angular js $scope.names . I want the data to be populated on the same page itself .

Home.jsp

```
<script>
       var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

       function MyController($scope, $http) {

              $scope.getPersonDataFromServer = function() {
                     $http({
                           method : 'GET'

                     }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                           //alert(data);
                           $scope.names= data;
                           console.log(data);

                     }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                           // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                           // or server returns response with an error status.
                           console.log("error");
                     });

              };

       };

</script>

</head>

<body style="text-align: center;" data-ng-app="myApp">
       <h4>US map</h4>
       <div>
              <img src="images/usmap.gif" alt="US MAP" width="529" height="334"
                     border='0' usemap='#usimage' align="middle">
       </div>
       <div
              data-ng-controller="MyController">
<div >
<map name='usimage'>
                     <!--- BEGIN: East --->
                     <area shape='polygon' coords='489,52,502,31,513,32,518,54,490,71' data-ng-click ="getPersonDataFromServer()" href='home.web?statechoice=ME' target="_self"  alt='Maine'>
<map>
</div>
<div >

                     <table  border ="1" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                     <tr style="background-color:lightgray;">
                                  <th>Cities</th>

                     <tr data-ng-repeat="city in names">
                                  <td>{{city}}</td>

              </div>
```

Controller - I am setting the value in impl class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home.web", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
                     "application/xml", "application/json" })

       public  @ResponseBody List<String> getUSCity() {

              String statechoice ="ME";
              List<String> msa = new ArrayList<String>();           
              msa = msaService.getMsaCodes(statechoice);

              return msa;
       }
```

I am not able to identify if I am missing anything .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you console log `data` or `$scope.names`?
In the error portion, pass the error object to the callback function and log it out if there is an error. This will provide with more details that could help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: it is going in success function .Array is printed in the console . After that it throws 406 error

Comment: Not that it matters much right now but I would highly recommend you to read this for future Angular 1 development: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1

Comment: It might help in the future for you to separate concerns. Business logic should go into services instead of your controller. Ideally, the service/factory should be prepared to make the http request. If using $stateProvider || $routeProvider, this should be responsible for making the asynchronous request and then waiting for it resolve. The controller should only be the medium that holds the final data.

Comment: I'm also not entirely familiar with the $http related syntax you're using here. What's the URL that you're sending the request towards? Are we sending a request to the back-end or is it CORS?

Comment: In my experience with Angular 1 and MongoDB, I would typically make a request to the back-end, which is responsible for making the AJAX request and formatting the data. The service is only responsible for connecting the front-end and back-end together. Furthermore, the $stateProvider will resolve the request asynchronously when it is necessary and then the controller is the link before the data hits the view.

In service:
$http.get('www.mywebsite.com/api/data').then((request) => request.data)

Answer (score 0):

It may be the fact that your REST endpoint produces both JSON and XML. The 406 HTTP error is "Not Acceptable", meaning that the client request's **Accept** header did not match what the server is returning. By default, the $http service only accepts text and JSON as return types. Try removing the application/xml in your REST endpoint's @Produces annotation, or check out [the $http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for instruction on how to change the default Accept header for $http.

Comment: Oh .sorry . I have missed the URL in the above code ,but I have tried this . Still the error is coming

Comment: Please see my new proposed answer above